# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read a few other Questions here and they didn't seem to have an answer, not sure if this sort of error occurs during a case by case basis.

I'm not too familiar with the wizardry of Javascript, I have the text "$9.99 USD/month" and I was trying to break it apart in spans. This is what I have:

```
    var str = jQuery(".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data").html();
    var month = /(\/\month)/;
    var year = /(\/\year)/;
    var dollar = /\$/g;
    var currency = /(USD)/;

    str = str.replace(dollar, '<span class="mm-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>');
    str = str.replace(currency, '<span class="mm-data-currency">(USD)</span>');
    str = str.replace(month, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Monthly</span>');
    str = str.replace(year, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Yearly</span>');
    jQuery(".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data").html(str);
```

So, this actually does work on the front-end. I get all my spans and classes as needed, but for some reason, I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" when I look in console, and this is causing some other Javascript elements on my page to break. I am not sure how to debug/fix this.

Comment: Has the content loaded before you're initiating your script? It's possible that your `.mm-data` doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

A quick test shows that the code isn't your problem, most likely you are [executing this code before the DOM has finished loading](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) in the HTML content so the element you are looking for (`".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data"`) does not yet exist, thus your str variable is undefined.

```js
 var str = "$9.99 USD/month";
 var month = /(\/\month)/;
 var year = /(\/\year)/;
 var dollar = /\$/g;
 var currency = /(USD)/;

    str = str.replace(dollar, '<span class="mm-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>');
    str = str.replace(currency, '<span class="mm-data-currency">(USD)</span>');
    str = str.replace(month, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Monthly</span>');
    str = str.replace(year, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Yearly</span>');
    console.log(str);
```

#### EDIT - *element only appears on one page*

To handle elements that aren't universal you are going to need to wrap a [conditional](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/) around your execution:

```
if (jQuery(".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data").length) {
  let str = jQuery(".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data").html()
    .replace(/\$/g, '<span class="mm-data-sign"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i></span>')
    .replace(/(USD)/, '<span class="mm-data-currency">(USD)</span>')
    .replace(/(\/\month)/, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Monthly</span>')
    .replace(/(\/\year)/, '<span class="mm-data-plan">/Yearly</span>');
}
```

Comment: That class only appears on one specific page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details?
The message shows the line is causing this?
Is the var str undefined on first replace call?

If you try this

```
var str = jQuery(".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data").html() || '';
```

can fix your problem?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that "str" is not yet defined when you try to replace it's content. Do you have an element with ".mm-checkoutSection2 ul li .mm-data" on the HTML side where the js is called?